# Run a second program on linux box with cPanel

Tags: linux, centos

I have a box with Linux on it that I have CentOS 7 on and I am running my cPanel enabled web server on. My mate has a game server script he would like me to run for him, called FiveM which is used for GTA 5 online. It runs on a port I am not using for my cPanel already, what I am wondering is is there a way I can run the server on the same distro of CentOS my cPanel is running on, in the background or does it need to be on it's own partition? I have already allocated the whole RAM and HD space of the server to the partition the cPanel server is installed on, but I am not sure if it's possible to run a second program on a server running cPanel already.

Has this been done before? Should I just run a second box?

Comment: If they're running on different ports, what's the problem?

Comment: I am not sure how to start the second process behind the cPanel script without stopping the cPanel.

Comment: CPanel is just an application, FiveM is another application. Try searching through the [FiveM wiki site](https://wiki.fivem.net) for the installation guide.

Comment: cPanel heavily modifies your version of CentOS tho. I shall try this and see if they work together, thanks so much for your time! :)